# java JFileChooser how to temporarily disable file selection window

Tags: java, jfilechooser

Is there a way how to temporarily disable file chooser in the `JFileChooser` window?
I created custom preview `JPanel` and I need the next file selection to be made only after the file preview is done/created (it created image from Wavefront OBJ files when such obj file is selected in the file chooser window).
Maybe some sort of disabling the whole file selection window part?

**EDIT:**

I was searching around here a bit more and found post [Start a JFileChooser with files ordered by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429779/start-a-jfilechooser-with-files-ordered-by-date/16430214#16430214). Now if I understood it right, then according to it, this piece of code should in fact enabling access to `FilePane` inside the `JFileCHooser` (of course, I downloaded the [SwingUtils.java](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/13/swing-utils/) class first):

```
JTable table = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(JTable.class, fileChooser).get(0);
```

But when I do that, I got error in NetBeansIDE saying: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0`
Does anyone know why?

I also found post [How to disable file input field in JFileChooser?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4169224/19018243), according to which this piece of code accessing the JFileChooser's textfield showing the selected file name:

```
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.lang.reflect.Field;
import javax.swing.JFileChooser;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalFileChooserUI;

public class FileChooser {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
  Frame f = new JFrame();
  JFileChooser jFileChooser = new JFileChooser();
  MetalFileChooserUI ui = (MetalFileChooserUI)jFileChooser.getUI();
  Field field = MetalFileChooserUI.class.getDeclaredField("fileNameTextField");
  field.setAccessible(true);
  JTextField tf = (JTextField) field.get(ui);
  tf.setEditable(false);
  tf.setEnabled(false);
  jFileChooser.showDialog(f, "Select");
  f.dispose();
 }
}
```

So, by inspecting all available fields I found out there is one called "filePane". So I took a risk and try to imitate the above code just with a few changes so that the `FilePane` would be targeted instead like this:

```
Field fieldB = MetalFileChooserUI.class.getDeclaredField("filePane");
fieldB.setAccessible(true);
FilePane filePane = (FilePane) fieldB.get(ui);
filePane.setEnabled(false);
```

I thought the code above would disable the file selection part of the `JFileChooser` window, but it did absolutely nothing, unfortunately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after a while I've solved it myself by playing further with the above code ending up with this functioning piece below:

```
FilePane filePane = SwingUtils.getDescendantsOfType(FilePane.class, fileChooser).get(0);
filePane.setEnabled(false);//<- this line doesn't work, but I'll leave it here so others know
filePane.setVisible(false);
```